# Save position of specific item in RecyclerView after new data insertion

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I implement `RecyclerView` which have two `ViewType`. The list is dynamic and when user scroll down/up it add some items. In my `RecyclerView` just one of the item has different `ViewType` (consider this as expandable list which only one of item expand at a time).

I save position for expanded item But when new data added this position changed and I lost expanded item. Because data added in scroll down/up, updating expanded item according to size of new data is not good Idea.

One thing to mention is that I want to scroll to expanded item at first load. so I guess saving position would be best choice. (I guess but I'm not sure);

I want to know what's the efficient way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Implement hashcode and equals method, using this get the position for the expanded model object.

Example :

```
public class Employee {
    protected long   employeeId;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;

    public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o == null)                return false;
    if(!(o instanceof) Employee) return false;

    Employee other = (Employee) o;
    if(this.employeeId != other.employeeId)      return false;
    if(! this.firstName.equals(other.firstName)) return false;
    if(! this.lastName.equals(other.lastName))   return false;

    return true;
  }

  public int hashCode(){
    return (int) employeeId;
  }
}

// To get the index of expanded item
int expandedItemIndex = EmployeeList.indexOf(expandedEmployeeModel);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(expandedItemIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely you use model for loading data to RecyclerView. And  this model (for ex. ContactModel) contains different values for your ViewHolders.

What is point, that you use special references for that saved position. **What you need to do, it's just put that position (of expanded item) to current model.** And after all most works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. at first load of items I want to move to expanded item do you have any idea How to do this ? I use position of items because I used **recyclerview.scrolltoPosition()** for solving this issue but with your solution it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Implement hashcode and equals in the model class you are using. Use ArrayList.indexOf(model_object) to get the position of expanded item, use recyclerview.scrolltoPosition() on it. Hope it helps. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Comment: @AlokOmkar really thanks for your hint. post it as a solution :)